# Setting multiple integers for "If" statement test value

Tags: swift, if-statement, logical-operators

I am trying to set multiple integer tests for a single variable in the `if` statement. The logical operators won't work due to the fact that they must be boolean.

For example:

```
if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.fake {
    groundspeed = 35.0
    self.button1value++

    if(button1value == 2) {
      groundspeed = 5.0
    }

    if(button1value == 4){
        groundspeed = 5.0
    }

    if(button1value == 6) {
        groundspeed = 5.0
    }
}
```

The goal is to be able to put all of the even numbers shown into just one `if` statement.

Answer (score 21):

If we just want to check whether or not `button1value` is even, we can do that using the modulo (`%`) operator:

```
if button1value % 2 == 0 {
    // button1value is even
    groundspeed = 5.0
}
```

If we're checking for some other sort of set, we can use a `switch` statement:

```
switch button1value {
    case 2,4,6:
        // button1value is 2, 4, or 6
        groundspeed = 5.0
    default:
        // button1value is something else
}
```

We can do other neat tricks with Swift's `switch` statement too, if we want:

```
switch (button1value % 2, button1value % 3) {
    case (0,0):
        // button1value is an even multiple of 3 (6,12,18...)
    case (0,_):
        // button1value is an even number not a multiple of three (2,4,8,10,14...)
    case (_,0):
        // button1value is an odd multiple of three (3,9,15,21...)
    default:
        // button1value is none of the above: (1,5,7,11...)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Check and accept nhgrif's answer for a better variant. But just for the sake of completeness if you want to keep your way, you can use the logical OR operator `||`

```
if(button1value == 2 || button1value == 4 || button1value == 6) {
    groundspeed = 5.0
}
```

That checks if any of the given boolean-values is true.

There is also a logical AND operator `&&`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `contains` to check for multiple values.  Just pass an array containing the values you want to test and the variable as the second parameter:

```
if contains([2, 4, 6], button1value) {
    groundspeed = 5.0
}
```

Comment: How does the efficiency of this compare to an `if`-`else` or a `switch` statement though?  (Still upvoting though because there are definitely times & places for `contains()`)

Comment: Yes, it will be slower, but nothing you're likely to notice unless you're executing it thousands of times.

Comment: (Or have significantly larger number of elements in the array.  OP wanted *all even numbers* remember.)

Comment: *All of the even numbers shown* implies only 2, 4, and 6. If the OP really means *all even numbers* then your `% 2` is by far the best solution. In fact, I would choose that even if there were just a few numbers if all the desired ones were even and all of the others were odd.